# CSS overflow issues with Animate.css and Bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have AngularJS, Bootstrap, and Animate.css set up so that when I click on a panel header, the body slides in.

To keep the animation contained to the panel, I've added `overflow-x: hidden` to the `.panel` class.

However, this causes the dropdown plugin I'm using in the `.panel-body` div to be cut off (Silvio Moreto's excellent **[bootstrap-select plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)** implemented using **[an AngularJS directive](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)**).

See below:

[image]

Here's a plunker so you can view the code and see for yourself:

## http://plnkr.co/edit/dAP9OqFI0h95qtC56FTE?p=preview

If I use a regular `<select>` instead of the plugin, it works fine.

The dropdown plugin adds markup, which I think is at the mercy of the `overflow-x` rule of the `.panel` div... and therefore causing the issue.

**Is there anyway I can modify my markup/CSS to allow the dropdown to "break out" of the panel when selected?**

Preferably, I'd like to avoid modifying the CSS of the plugin.

Thanks for your help! :)

**Edit:**
To clarify, this is the effect I would like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBsHL.png :)

---

## Resolved!

I used a variation of the accepted answer, where I make use of ngAnimate's `beforeRemoveClass` method to hide overflow immediately before the "ng-hide" class is removed, and then add it back after the css animations have completed:

```
app.animation('.slide', function() {

    return {

        removeClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {

                var duration = 0.3;

                element.css('-webkit-animation', 'slideInRight '+(duration)+'s')
                       .css('-moz-animation', 'slideInRight '+(duration)+'s')
                       .css('-o-animation', 'slideInRight '+(duration)+'s')
                       .css('animation', 'slideInRight '+(duration)+'s');

                // After the css animation has completed, allow overflow on the parent panel again.
                setTimeout(function(){
                    element.closest('.panel').removeClass('no-overflow');
                }, (duration * 1000));

                doneFn();
        },

        beforeRemoveClass: function(element, className, doneFn){

            // Prevent overflow on closest panel
            element.closest('.panel').addClass('no-overflow');

            doneFn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 First off, thanks for you reply! :) I haven't tried that, but I'm hoping to avoid Javascript (especially event-based JS) if possible... if I can't achieve it with CSS, I'll look into a JS alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this would be to create a [Javascript animation in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

You define the animation in jQuery, and add/remove the appropriate CSS rules before and after the animation has occurred. Here is an example animation which uses opacity:

```
myModule.animation('.js-slide', function() {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {

      // Hide the overflow before the animation starts  
      $('.panel').css('overflow', 'hidden');

      // Perform the animation with jQuery
      element.css('opacity',0);
      jQuery(element).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500, function() {

        // Show the overflow after the animation completes
        $('.panel').css('overflow', 'visible');
        done();

      });

    },
  }
});
```

Then to use this example animation, the HTML would look like this:

```
<div ng-if="panelBodyVisible" class="panel-body js-slide"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) This is actually what I'm considering doing (see my issues with Robin's answer above), but ideally I'm looking for a pure CSS solution. I'll keep you posted and if I have to resort to this I'll accept :)

Comment: @Andrew I do recommend this one, now that you clarified what you want. It would be hard to rely it only on CSS because of the overflow issue.

Comment: @bcole I used a variation of your solution, everything works great! See my edit on the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `panel` class.

Then add this on your css to this :

```
.form-control {
  height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer better than the one I posted, and [I tested it and it works even with the `overflow-x: hidden;` property still enabled](http://plnkr.co/edit/SILBZK73WhNjcpSUtmZw?p=preview).

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan Thanks for your reply! :) This is very close, but this is the effect I'm looking for: [http://i.imgur.com/WMluRjg.png](http://i.imgur.com/WMluRjg.png)... and [here's the corresponding Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcidypJKHdyo1Xd4vNU8?p=preview). My issue with this Plunker is that the animation isn't contained to the panel (it starts outside it).

Comment: I got a bit ugly code here http://plnkr.co/edit/fhqkLR32KNlaLbJCbl0m?p=preview. Added a container and having the `panel` element a bit large margin bottom.